# Tensorflow: share mutable tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to pass a mutable value between functions for debugging purposes. Shared variables do not work as their assignment needs `.eval()` or `sess.run()` to be called, while I am located deep inside my procedures and output values using `tf.Print()`.

Suppose I want to output the number of layer for which gradient is computed at the moment, so I tried to do it with tensor:

```
# initialize shared tensor somewhere outside
LevelCounter = tf.constant(5, name ="sharedtensor", dtype=tf.int32)

#function that updates shared tensor value    
def process_gradient_layer_counter():  # show current layer
    #access shared tensor
    current_layer = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("sharedtensor:0")
    #modify it's value
    current_layer -= 1

    # My attempt: save it again using the same name. Didn't work
    current_layer = tf.identity(current_layer, name ="sharedtensor")

    return current_layer

# compute gradient
@tf.RegisterGradient('MyGrad')
def mygrad(op, grad): 
    x = op.inputs[0]
    # ... compute grad_new, which I want to debug ... #

    #Display layer counter
    grad_new = tf.Print(grad_new, [process_gradient_layer_counter()], message = 'debug: ')

    return grad_new
```

But unfortunately, this code outputs always 4. What should I do to share mutable values between the different functions without breaking the workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on, think about the computational graph created. Every time mygrad() is called, it creates `tf.identity(sharedtensor-1)` node. You have a bunch of nodes that are doing the same computation, so it's not surprising you see the same result printed.

Having mutable internal state is possible by forcing `assign_add` through control dependencies, but it's unintuitive and prone to errors. Better approach could be to replace your `process_gradient_layer_counter` with a `tf.py_func` which updates a global Python variable

Comment: Thanks! However py_func in fact either annihilates my GPU or at least slows down significantly. The gradients are definitely called in a sequence,  also I have noticed that tensor name is "sharedtensor:0". So maybe I can somehow create a new node each time and access the last one from those nodes? Some memory leak would be acceptable for debugging...

Comment: If there is no other way, then I will go with CPU and pyfunc solution...

Comment: instead of adding to `sharedtensor` you could add to some global python variable containing the last addition

Comment: But variable needs to be evaluated, how can I do that from inside the gradients which are applied in Optimizer procedure?

Comment: it's a Python variable, it gets evaluated during graph construction

Comment: Ok, it seems to work: when I pass it to `tf.Print(grad_new,[pyth_var],...)` it gets evaluated  and printed.Thanks very much! Looks like I can add or subtract tensor values from this variable and transfer some information in this way.